# What is the major difference between the Samsung NC20 and the N150 netbooks?

Tags: netbook

The Samsung NC10 seems to be a very popular netbook. I am confused about which netbook is it's natural 'big brother'.

I.e. I want an 11" - 12" screen and have looked at both the NC20 and the N510. The NC20 uses a different CPU to the NC10, while the N510 is newer and goes back to the Intel procesor.

Are these netbooks trying to target different markets?

Answer (score 0):

The N510 uses the [nVidia ION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Ion) platform for it's graphics, etc. - supporting DX10 gaming and HD video. Apparently the NC20 is not very good at multitasking.